# Alternate use of "Curation" as a noun

Tags: nouns, writing-style

Stylistically, can "Curation" be used as a noun to describe the items being curated, instead of the act of curating? (e.g., a curation, these selected curations, etc.)

Comment: What's wrong with "collection", which curators usually curate?

Answer (score 1):

The noun **curation** tends to be used to refer to the selecting and preserving of artifacts, not to a curated collection. Normally **collection** or **curated collection** refers to the curated items. If you used it to refer to the collection that usage would certainly be an outlier.